# biblatex error: Option 'url' already defined with OSCOLA

Tags: biblatex, oscola

I am a beginner and I am trying to use OSCOLA Style with `biblatex`. 
It's 2 days I am bashing my head on these errors:

[image]

Please help!

Comment: For future questions, please note that it is much better to post the code of your (ideally minimal) example document (and the errors) as text instead of uploading an image. Images can be hard to read, are not searched by search engines and pose a severe accessibility issue for people with screen readers. Images of code are particularly discouraging, because they require people to re-type your code before they can test it and play around with it.

Answer (score 1):

### Update

The issue is resolved in `oscola` v1.7 (2020/03/15) (see https://github.com/PaulStanley/oscola-biblatex/pull/8).

If possibly update your TeX system to obtain a current version of `oscola`.

The rest of the answer below is kept for historical interest.

---

This error occurs, because *someone* extended the scope of some of `biblatex`'s `standard.bbx` options from global to per-type and per-entry, see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/877 and https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/875 for background (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/866 for even more background). Amongst the options whose scope was extended are `url`, `doi` and `eprint`.

`biblatex` will not accept attempts to define an option if it has been defined before and will throw an error. `oscola` already defines the options `url`, `doi` and `eprint` at per-type and per-entry scopes.

Unfortunately, *someone* forgot to check `oscola` for compatibility with the change, so the `biblatex` update went out before the `oscola` author could be made aware of this change and adapt his style.

The issue was only discovered a while later by Ulrike Fischer (https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=52383705#52383705) and for now documents using `style=oscola,` will complain

```
! Package biblatex Error: Option 'url' already defined.

See the biblatex package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.135   \settoggle{bbx:url}{#1}}
                                
? 

! Package biblatex Error: Option 'doi' already defined.

See the biblatex package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.137   \settoggle{bbx:doi}{#1}}
                                
? 

! Package biblatex Error: Option 'eprint' already defined.

See the biblatex package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.139   \settoggle{bbx:eprint}{#1}}
                                   
?
```

because `biblatex`'s `standard.bbx` defines these options and then `oscola.bbx` tries to define them again.

A fix has been submitted to the `oscola-biblatex` GitHub repository: https://github.com/PaulStanley/oscola-biblatex/pull/8.

If you need to use `oscola` now, download `oscola.bbx` from the pull request (https://github.com/PaulStanley/oscola-biblatex/blob/28e6a54ef5c6d4b02e06cedee0123d7b92ec5857/oscola.bbx), put it into the same folder as your main `.tex` document, rename it to `oscola-fixed.bbx` and load `biblatex` as

```
\usepackage[bibstyle=oscola-fixed, citestyle=oscola, backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

instead of `\usepackage[style=oscola, backend=biber]{biblatex}`.

Comment: OOOOOMYGOOODDDDDDDDD!!!!! YES it works!!!!!!!!!!!! I am sooooooo happyyyyyyyyy!!!!!! Yes YEs YES! Thank you soOOOoOOOOOOooooooOOOO much!