# How can I get TeX Live to stop using the wrong package version (oscola)?

Tags: errors, packages, texlive, ubuntu

When attempting to use the OSCOLA style with `biblatex` I receive the error '! Package biblatex Error: Option 'url' already defined.' during compilation (running `pdflatex` from the command line).

Someone else asked about this and [the solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/532222/201812) was to update the `oscola` package to receive a fix. I had previously installed the very-behind version of TeX Live via `sudo apt install texlive-full`, so I uninstalled that and followed [the TUG guide](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) to manually installing the most recent version. I have updated my `PATH` and all.

`tlmgr list oscola` confirms I am using the most recent version (1.7). `tlmgr` and `pdflatex` are located in the right folders:

```
~$ whereis tlmgr
tlmgr: /usr/bin/tlmgr /usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr /usr/share/man/man1/tlmgr.1.gz
~$ whereis pdflatex
pdflatex: /usr/bin/pdflatex /usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex /usr/share/man/man1/pdflatex.1.gz
```

But I am still getting the same error when I try to compile. Looking at the transcript, it seems that it is looking in the correct place for every single package *except* `oscola` for some reason:

```
Document Class: report 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/abstract/abstract.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(/home/{username}/texmf/tex/latex/oscola/oscola.bbx
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/authortitle.bbx
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx))

! Package biblatex Error: Option 'url' already defined.
```

Looking the `/home/{username}/texmf/tex/latex/oscola/oscola.bbx` file it is clear that it is version 1.6. There is an `oscola.bbx` file at `/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oscola/` which is version 1.7.

How do I get `pdflatex` to use the correct version of `oscola`?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I just needed to delete the `/oscola/` folder within `/home/{username}/texmf/tex/latex/`. I don't know why this wasn't deleted by `apt` when I `remove`d, `autoremove`d and `purge`d my TeX Live installation.

Comment: `/home/{username}/texmf/` is the user-controlled `TEXMFHOME` directory. As far as I know no TeX distribution will actively try to interfere (delete/rename/move) with these files not even on a purge. But these files will usually have precedence over system-installed files. So it's good to keep an eye on `TEXMFHOME` and periodically check that the files you have there are still needed and not outdated.