# How to EMbed OSCOLA-FIXED style in a Class (Law Thesis by Rory Gresgson)

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, oscola

I had Problems in January to use OSCOLA due to a bug in the coding when they updated BibLatex. Fixed: [biblatex error: Option 'url' already defined with OSCOLA](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/532215/biblatex-error-option-url-already-defined-with-oscola)

I fixed it using the OSCOLA-FIXED.bbx

Now I am writing my thesis and I need to add it to a class document (law-thesis.cls), but it doesn't find it:

! Package biblatex Error: Style 'oscola-fixed' not found.

How do I integrate it in the class document?

Comment: Welcome to tex.se! The linked answer says about the fixed file: "put it into the same folder as your main `.tex` document". Is that where it is now, the same folder where your thesis is? Or is it in some other folder? TeX looks in the current folder first, and then some standard locations after, but won't know to look elsewhere, like the folder of a previous `.tex` project.

Comment: If you have updated your TeX system to obtain a current version of `oscola`, you may need to reset your `biblatex` command back to `\usepackage[style=oscola, ...]{biblatex}`.

Comment: I tried to put it in the same folder of the thesis.tex and also in the same folder of the class document and neither work

Comment: Update your system thoroughly (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864) and use `style=oscola,` instead of `style=oscola-fixed,`. The current release version of `biblatex-oscola` no longer has the bug from the linked question.

Comment: Thank you! It works!

Comment: @Cicada Do you want to type up a quick answer saying that (`biblatex-`)`oscola` has been fixed, so that `oscola-fixed` is no longer necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex-oscola` has been fixed, so the workaround `style=oscola-fixed,` is no longer needed. Use `style=oscola,` as normal.